# ASCI Escape Codes with #define value?

Tags: c, escaping

I have a #define'd value named HEIGHT with a value of 20.
I want to use the ASCI escape code "\033[HA" (where H is the number of lines the cursor is moved up.
However, when my code reads "\033[HEIGHTA", it is reading the 'H' as a different escape code (return cursor home). How can I include a #define'd value within an escape code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives, among them

1. Use a function instead of a macro to generate the escape code as needed.  For example,

   ```
   const char *cursor_up_seq() {
       static char sequence[12];
       if (sequence[0] == '\0') {
           // one-time initialization
           sprintf(sequence, "\033[%dA", HEIGHT);
       }
       return sequence;
   }
   ```
2. As a variation on (1), do not produce the escape sequence as a standalone entity at all.  Instead, embed it in whatever else you are printing, where it is natural to use (say) `printf()` to print the value of the `HEIGHT` macro.
3. But if you really want to produce a macro for a string literal containing the whole escape sequence, then you can do so by combining two C features:

   - the stringification (`#`) macro operator, and
   - automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals

   Another answer, now deleted, attempted to demonstrate that, but floundered on one of the gotchas in that area.  Here is a variation that works:

   ```
   #define HEIGHT 20
   #define STRINGIFY(x) #x
   #define STRINGIFY_VALUE(x) STRINGIFY(x)

   #define SEQUENCE "\033[" STRINGIFY_VALUE(HEIGHT) "A"
   ```

   The resulting `SEQUENCE` macro expands to `"\033[" "20" "A"`, which is 100% equivalent to `"\033[20A"` because of string literal concatenation.  The gotcha here is that you cannot use `STRINGIFY()` directly for this purpose, because that does not macro-expand its argument before converting it to a string (per the standard behavior of `#`).  Wrapping it in another macro layer (`STRINGIFY_VALUE`) results in that outer layer expanding the argument before presenting the result for stringification.